# Wordpress blog page featured image

Tags: wordpress

I like to use the page's featured images in a background image in the header. When I add a new page and set the featured image, it appears as background image works exactly what I wanted. But on a Blog main page (the Home, page of displaying posts) I set the featured image and in the header display the first post's featured image insetad the one I set at the page's featured image. Tried to find solution, but nothing works, don't know how to magae it. Here is my code that handle background image:

```
<div class="sub-header"
    <?php
        if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
            echo 'style="background-image: url(\'';
            echo $image[0];
            echo '\');"';
        endif;
    ?>
    >
</div>
```

Comment: Since the blog 'front page' is an archive page, you need to create a special case for it, and also define a custom image source, whether it's assigned in the customizer or hard coded.

Comment: I don't like to hardcode the image. It's better when user can change it. And tried the custom image source but that doesn't work either, it's displayed the firs't post's featured image.

Answer (score 0):

Make the custom image source, whether it's assigned in the customizer or hard coded.